# JOLT Tranformation using dynamic key value

Tags: arrays, json, transform, apache-nifi, jolt

I am trying covert the below JSON to a specific format

INPUT

```
{
  "var_name1" : "alarmID",
  "var_val1" : "12345678",
  "var_name2" : "witscsAlarmTime",
  "var_val2" : "2022-05-10T03:46:38.376Z",
  "var_name3" : "witscsAlarmSeverity",
  "var_val3" : "major",
  "var_name4" : "witscsAlarmBody",
  "var_val4" : "Enterprise Manager was unable to communicate",
  "var_name5" : "witscsAlarmToken"
}
```

Required Output

```json
{
  "trap_variables" : {
    "alarmID": "12345678", 
    "witscsAlarmTime": "2022-05-10T03:46:38.376Z", 
    "witscsAlarmSeverity": "major", 
    "witscsAlarmBody": "Enterprise Manager was unable to communicate"
  }
}
```

I am unable to build a JOLT spec which can dynamically change the key of the output. The var_name and var_val s of the input are not restricted to just 4 set of values, the set count can change from request to request.

What should be the JOLT spec to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use two successive **shift** operations through use of **`*`** wildcards for each group(`var_value(s)` and `var_name(s)`) such as

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "var_val*": "v[]",
      "var_name*": "n[]"
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "v": {
        "*": "trap_variables.@(2,n[&])"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

the ***demo*** on the site http://jolt-demo.appspot.com/ is

[image]

Comment: One problem noticed, In case I have just 1 set of value, "var_val*": "v", is not returning any array. This is failing the conversion.

Comment: The fix was easy. Just changed it to - ```"var_val*": "v[]",
"var_name*": "n[]",```

Comment: exactly, sure you can @SameerSaha